# I connect to my app using provider in Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I was getting this error when I was debugging by Application upon registration to flutter Firebase Firestore. I need help.

Stacktrace:

```
W/DynamiteModule( 2822): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 2822): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 2822): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you share the code that is causing the problem? only the error doesn't give enough information.